# Android one activity two animations

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to animate the activities of my app like Uber does.

For instance, the user is seeing the map, opens the menu and taps on "Your Trips", the menu closes and the "Your Trips" opens from bottom up. After that, the animation becames left to right or right to left depending on user choices.

So basicaly, from the menu, all activities animations are bottom up and after that the most common way (left to right / right to left). But when the user taps on the "X", the animation is from up to bottom.

I already did most of it, I using `onResume` and `onPause` methods to handle the animations.

When user taps on a menu item to go to `activityOne` I handle like this:

`activityOne` `onResume` method:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
```

When user taps on a item of `activityOne` to go to `activityTwo`

`activityOne` `onResume` method:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right_to_left, R.anim.slide_out_left_to_right);
```

But when the user goes back to `activityOne`, I want to slide the `activityTwo` from left to right to show the `activityOne` to give the "back effect".

The problem is that `activityOne` already has the animation from bottom up.

Can anyone point me to right direction to achieve this?

Is this the correct way to do it?

How to handle both animation on one activity?

Comment: check these out >> https://github.com/Wing-Li/Material-Animations-CN  

https://github.com/ImmortalZ/TransitionHelper

Comment: Ok, this can help me create transitions, but how can I handle tow transitions on the same activiy? First from the menu and then from the back button of an activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I was mixing up the animations for the activities.

From the menu:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
```

On back button:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left_to_right, R.anim.slide_out_right_to_left);
```

Everything else:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right_to_left, R.anim.slide_out_left_to_right);
```